# What does a spell range of "25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels" mean?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

The spell *disrupt undead* has the text

> Range: Close (25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels)

Does this mean 25 feet at first level, +5 feet at level 3, 5, 7, 9, etc.?

*or*

Does it mean 25 feet at first level, +5 feet at level 2, 4, 6, 8, etc.?

Answer (score 23):

This format is expanded, somewhat, in the [Magic Overview](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#close):

> #### Close
>
> The spell reaches as far as 25 feet away from you. The maximum range increases by 5 feet for every two full caster levels.

Since it does not use phrasing like “every two levels after 1st,” which the rules do sometimes use, it seems safe to me to assume that it increases by 5 feet on every even level (so 25 ft. at 1st, 30 ft. at 2nd, 35 ft. at 4th, 40 ft. at 6th, and so on). Certainly, this is the meaning I have always used and always seen others use.

Answer (score 9):

#### 25 feet, +5 at level 2, 4, etc

This is more clearly explained in the *Player's Handbook*, p. 185, under *Range*:

> **Close:** The spell reaches as far as 25 feet away from you. The maximum range increases by 5 feet for every two full caster levels (30 feet and 2nd caster level, 35 feet at 4th caster level, and so on).

Comment: Weird that this wasn’t included in the SRD, but great find! Didn’t even think this would be something they’d leave out of the SRD and never checked the PHB.